# Change item font style when referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumitem, cleveref

I constructed my own list `longmainenum` which has bold item labels. Now when referencing them with `cleveref`'s `\cref`I want to have the bold font removed. A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cleveref, enumitem}

\newlist{longmainenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[longmainenum]{label=\textbf{(\alph*)}}

\creflabelformat{longmainenumi}{\textmd{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longmainenum}
    \item\label{here} Something.
    \item More.
\end{longmainenum}

\labelcref{here}.

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot remove the bold font with `\textmd`. It still remains bold face. (Oddly enough, when I try to add an additional font command like, e.g., `\textit`, it works.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Font command like \textit and \textbf can add up, but \textmd and \textbf exclude each other and so the inner one wins. In your case I would simply set the font with the font command.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cleveref, enumitem}

\newlist{longmainenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[longmainenum]{label=(\alph*),font=\bfseries}

\creflabelformat{longmainenumi}{#1}

\begin{document}

\textmd{\textbf{blalba}}

\begin{longmainenum}
    \item\label{here} Something.
    \item More.
\end{longmainenum}

\labelcref{here}.

\end{document}
```

(Actually I would avoid bold labels. Imho they don't look good.)

Comment: Thanks. In my case, they are used to distinguish several parts of a theorem-like "Remark", where bold face makes sense (as the "Remark" is bold itself).

Comment: Ulrike's answer implicitly fixes the source of your problem: the font should not be a part of the label (which is just `(\alph*)` in the answer), but of the list formatting. You should do the same with the parentheses, if you'll want to refer to the item without them. (E.g., how will you format a range like `(13-15)`?